# Can I get admitted to a master's program at top European university with an average GPA?

Tags: masters, gpa, business-school, denmark, guaranteed-admissions

I study business economics, and I would like to study abroad in Denmark, precisely in Aarhus.

I've already talked with the staff via email, and despite the fact that they are a top university in Europe in the area of business, administration / management and finance, they have no restrictions on intake, taking in consideration only ECTS and English score.

Why do they do that? Can I be sure of  passing the selection criteria for admission  if I have an average or not excellent GPA (example: 3.0, 3.3)?

Comment: Top universities demand better than average GPA.

Comment: I don't wish to be unkind, but if they take your English writing skills into account you certainly want to improve those before you apply.

Comment: Hi astronat , I know my English isn't so good , can you say me what have I done wrong ? Ah I ve just read now the correction on my post , yes I know I be written it fastly without thinking too much , anyway thank you

Comment: Hopefully the edit by @GoodDeeds makes it clear, but your punctuation was all incorrect (unnecessary spaces before every mark), and your grammar, spelling and word choice isn't quite right (e.g. your question to me just then should be "can you *tell* me what I have done wrong?"). My advice is to try and read widely in English, perhaps things like the Harry Potter books, to get a better feel for idiomatic English.

Comment: Do also space before mark matter ? God that's why a lot of people are telling me the same , but I didn't think it was so necessary

Comment: It doesn't really change the meaning (I can understand what you're writing) but it looks very strange. It's a very simple thing to change to make your written English look much better, so why not do it?

Answer (score 1):

> they have no restriction intakes ,

> Why they do that ?

Caveat: I'm in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) and in a STEM field.

Many European countries have rather open admission systems for university, in particular if the program is not overcrowded. These programs in turn tend to have high failure rates at exams.

The philosophy behind this is that everyone should get their chance, but to go on, you need to produce the goods.

Also, since the pace and organizational requirements at university are quite different from school, many students struggle with their exams in their first year, even students who then "wake up" and become top students towards their BSc thesis. This makes it a bit difficult to use a grade average for distinguishing consistently weak students from very good students who had a slow start.

---

> taking in consideration only ects and english Score

ECTS do not measure your performance, but roughly how many courses you took and studied so you did pass. English score probably because they teach in English.

ECTS are to weed out applicants for whom the courses are not meant (if you don't meet them, you'll need to attend at least some Bachelor level courses) - I expect the ECTS points also need to be in certain subjects. A BSc in physics won't get you admission.

English score is to weed out applicants who cannot possibly follow courses taught in English.